# How to rewrite Tensorflow architecture in PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I have this UNet architecture in Tensorflow.

```
def make_generator_model():
    f = config.base_number_of_filters
    k = config.kernel_size
    s = config.strides
    sz = config.train_size
    c = config.channels
    pad = padding_power_2((sz, sz))

    if sz <= 128:
        raise RuntimeError("Input size must be larger than 128 for this U-Net model")

    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((sz, sz, c), name="ginput")
    inputs_pad = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(pad, name="gpad")(inputs)

    # Encoder layers
    # Input is sz x sz x c
    ge1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(f, k, s, padding="same", name="geconv1")(inputs_pad)
    # Input is sz2 x sz2 x f
    ge2 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(config.leak, name="geact1")(ge1)
    ge2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2*f, k, s, padding="same", name="geconv2")(ge2)
    ge2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gebn2")(ge2)
    # Input is sz4 x sz4 x 2f
    ge3 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(config.leak, name="geact2")(ge2)
    ge3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4*f, k, s, padding="same", name="geconv3")(ge3)
    ge3 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gebn3")(ge3)
    # Input is sz8 x sz8 x 4f
    ge4 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(config.leak, name="geact3")(ge3)
    ge4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8*f, k, s, padding="same", name="geconv4")(ge4)
    ge4 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gebn4")(ge4)

    # Input is sz16 x sz16 x 8f
    ge5 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(config.leak, name="geact4")(ge4)
    ge5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8*f, k, s, padding="same", name="geconv5")(ge5)
    ge5 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gebn5")(ge5)

    # Input is sz32 x sz32 x 8f
    ge6 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(config.leak, name="geact5")(ge5)
    ge6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8*f, k, s, padding="same", name="geconv6")(ge6)
    ge6 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gebn6")(ge6)

    # Input is sz64 x sz64 x 8f
    ge7 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(config.leak, name="geact6")(ge6)
    ge7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8*f, k, s, padding="same", name="geconv7")(ge7)
    ge7 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gebn7")(ge7)

    # Input is sz128 x sz128 x 8f
    ge8 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(config.leak, name="geact7")(ge7)
    ge8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8*f, k, s, padding="same", name="geconv8")(ge8)
    ge8 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gebn8")(ge8)

    # Input is sz256 x sz256 x 8f
    # Decoder layers with skip connections
    gd1 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.0, name="geact8")(ge8)
    gd1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(8*f, k, s, padding="same", name="gdconv1")(gd1)
    gd1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gdbn1")(gd1)
    gd1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(config.dropout_rate, name="gddrop1")(gd1)

    # Input is sz128 x sz128 x 8f
    gd1 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([gd1, ge7], axis=3, name="gdcat1")
    gd2 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.0, name="gdact1")(gd1)
    gd2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(8*f, k, s, padding="same", name="gdconv2")(gd2)
    gd2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gdbn2")(gd2)
    gd2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(config.dropout_rate, name="gddrop2")(gd2)

    # Input is sz64 x sz64 x 8f
    gd2 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([gd2, ge6], axis=3, name="gdcat2")
    gd3 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.0, name="gdact2")(gd2)
    gd3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(8*f, k, s, padding="same", name="gdconv3")(gd3)
    gd3 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gdbn3")(gd3)
    gd3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(config.dropout_rate, name="gddrop3")(gd3)

    # Input is sz32 x sz32 x 8f
    gd3 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([gd3, ge5], axis=3, name="gdcat3")
    gd4 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.0, name="gdact3")(gd3)
    gd4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(8*f, k, s, padding="same", name="gdconv4")(gd4)
    gd4 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gdbn4")(gd4)
    # Input is sz16 x sz16 x 8f
    gd4 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([gd4, ge4], axis=3, name="gdcat4")
    gd5 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.0, name="gdact4")(gd4)
    gd5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(4*f, k, s, padding="same", name="gdconv5")(gd5)
    gd5 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gdbn5")(gd5)
    gd5 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([gd5, ge3], axis=3, name="gdcat5")
    # Input is sz8 x sz8 x 4f
    gd6 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.0, name="gdact5")(gd5)
    gd6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(2*f, k, s, padding="same", name="gdconv6")(gd6)
    gd6 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gdbn6")(gd6)
    # Input is sz4 x sz4 x 2f
    gd6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([gd6, ge2], axis=3, name="gdcat6")
    gd7 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.0, name="gdact6")(gd6)
    gd7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(f, k, s, padding="same", name="gdconv7")(gd7)
    gd7 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gdbn7")(gd7)
    # Input is sz2 x sz2 x f
    gd7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([gd7, ge1], axis=3, name="gdcat7")
    gd8 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.0)(gd7)
    gd8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(c, k, s, padding="same", activation="tanh", 
                          name="gdconvout")(gd8)
    # Input is sz x sz x nc
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(pad, name="gcrop")(gd8)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="cond_gen")
  
    return model
```

So far, this has been my attempt at rewriting it in Pytorch:

```
def generator_model():
    num_filters = config.filters_num
    kernel_size = config.kernel_size
    strides = config.strides
    train_size = config.train_size
    channels = config.channels
    padding = padding_power_2((train_size,train_size))

    if train_size <= 128:
        raise RuntimeError("Input size must be larger than 128 for this UNET model")

    inputs = nn.input((train_size, train_size, channels), name="input") # input is train_size * train_size
    input_padding = nn.ZeroPad2d(padding)(inputs)

    # Encode layers
    # Input is train_size * train_size * channels
    ge1 = nn.Conv2d(num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding='same')(input_padding)

    # Input size is train_size * train_size * num_filters
    ge2 = nn.LeakyReLU(config.leak)(ge1)
    ge2 = nn.Conv2d(2*num_filters, kernel_size, strides,padding='same')(ge2)
    ge2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ge2)

    # Input size is train_size * train_size * 2*num_filters
    ge3 = nn.LeakyReLU(config.leak)(ge2)
    ge3 = nn.Conv2d(4*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding='same')(ge3)
    ge3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ge3)

    # Input is sz8 x sz8 x 4f
    ge4 = nn.LeakyReLU(config.leak)(ge3)
    ge4 = nn.Conv2d(8*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding="same")(ge4)
    ge4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ge4)

    # Input is sz16 x sz16 x 8f
    ge5 = nn.LeakyReLU(config.leak)(ge4)
    ge5 = nn.Conv2d(8*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding="same")(ge5)
    ge5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ge5)

    # Input is sz32 x sz32 x 8f
    ge6 = nn.LeakyReLU(config.leak)(ge5)
    ge6 = nn.Conv2d(8*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding="same")(ge6)
    ge6 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ge6)

    # Input is sz64 x sz64 x 8f
    ge7 = nn.LeakyReLU(config.leak)(ge6)
    ge7 = nn.Conv2d(8*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding="same")(ge7)
    ge7 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ge7)

    # Input is sz128 x sz128 x 8f
    ge8 = nn.LeakyReLU(config.leak)(ge7)
    ge8 = nn.Conv2d(8*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding="same")(ge8)
    ge8 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ge8)

    # Input is sz256 x sz256 x 8f
    # Decoder layers with skip connections
    gd1 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.0)(ge8)
    gd1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(8*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding=padding)(gd1)
    gd1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(gd1)
    gd1 = nn.Dropout(config.dropout)(gd1)

    # Input is sz128 x sz128 x 8f
    gd1 = torch.cat([gd1, ge7])
    gd2 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.0)(gd1)
    gd2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(8*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding=padding)(gd2)
    gd2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(gd2)
    gd2 = nn.Dropout(config.dropout)(gd2)

    # Input is sz64 x sz64 x 8f
    gd2 = torch.cat([gd2, ge6])
    gd3 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.0)(gd2)
    gd3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(8*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding=padding)(gd3)
    gd3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(gd3)
    gd3 = nn.Dropout(config.dropout)(gd3)

    # Input is sz32 x sz32 x 8f
    gd3 = torch.cat([gd3, ge5])
    gd4 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.0)(gd3)
    gd4 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(8*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding=padding)(gd4)
    gd4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(gd4)
    gd4 = nn.Dropout(config.dropout)(gd4)

    # Input is sz16 x sz16 x 8f
    gd4 = torch.cat([gd4, ge4])
    gd5 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.0)(gd4)
    gd5 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(4*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding=padding)(gd5)
    gd5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(gd5)(gd5)
    gd5 = torch.cat([gd5, ge3])

    # Input is sz8 x sz8 x 4f
    gd6 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.0)(gd5)
    gd6 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(2*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding=padding)(gd6)
    gd6 = nn.BatchNorm2d(gd6)

    # Input is sz4 x sz4 x 2f
    gd6 = torch.cat([gd6, ge2])
    gd7 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.0)(gd6)
    gd7 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(8*num_filters, kernel_size, strides, padding=padding)(gd7)
    gd7 = nn.BatchNorm2d(gd7)

    # Input is sz2 x sz2 x f
    gd7 = torch.cat([gd7, ge1])
    gd8 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.0)(gd7)
    gd8 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(channels, kernel_size, strides, padding=padding)(gd8)

    # Input is sz x sz x nc
    outputs = nn.Cropping2D(pad, name="gcrop")(gd8)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="cond_gen")

    return model
```

I'm not completely done but there are a few roadblocks I hit.

First, how can I rewrite `inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((sz, sz, c), name="ginput")` in Torch? There is no `nn.Input()` function out there.

In tensorflow, there is concatenation happening with the output of a Batch Normalization like this:

```
gd6 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name="gdbn6")(gd6)
    # Input is sz4 x sz4 x 2f
    gd6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([gd6, ge2], axis=3, name="gdcat6")
```

When I try to do the same in Pytorch like this:

```
gd6 = nn.BatchNorm2d(gd6)

    # Input is sz4 x sz4 x 2f
    gd6 = torch.cat([gd6, ge2])
```

I am told that Torch expects a tuple or list of tensors for `gd6`. How can I adjust it as such?

Finally, in TensorFlow, there is a 2d cropping operation like this:

```
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(pad, name="gcrop")(gd8)
```

I couldn't figure out exactly how to do this in Pytorch.

There could be other mistakes that I've made but so far these are where I am stuck.

Comment: Pytorch models are generally constructed with a `torch.nn.Module`, which contains an init , which creates all of your models parameters (weights, biases, batch norms coefficients, etc), and a `forward` which applies these layers/functions in the way you want. Please see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/modules.html for help.

Comment: @jhso Thanks but there are some functions that I couldn't equate with Tensorflow. Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: Yes, so you can use torch.cat in the `forward` function when you define the flow of your model, because you're dealing with tensors of data, rather than layer definitions as you have above. This also applies for cropping, as you can simply use Numpy-style indexing to remove data from your tensor (like `arr = arr[:,:,pad//2:-pad//2, pad//2:-pad//2]`). Please try and create a simple model and expand from that rather than jumping straight into something complex like the above.